# How to dynamically pass array JSON as input to javascript adapters?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

My input data is given below. How do i parse this to send it from my app to the adapter. Help me out by giving some examples for PUT request and adapter sample code.

```
var data = { 
        "apps" : [{
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.youtube",
                "version" : 112753132
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.motocare",
                "version" : 2
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.providers.telephony",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.gallery3d",
                "version" : 40301
            }, {
                "pkg" : "io.appium.settings",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox",
                "version" : 300682618
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.providers.calendar",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.providers.media",
                "version" : 800
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.docs",
                "version" : 62731433
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.onetimeinitializer",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.xe.currency",
                "version" : 101
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.bug2go",
                "version" : 0
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.camera",
                "version" : 50002104
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.wallpapercropper",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.sample.printer",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.javacodegeeks.android.locationservicetest",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.konylabs.WAI",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.verizon.permissions.vzwappapn",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.ccc.devicemanagement",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.android.fmradio",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.sensorhub.stml0.updater",
                "version" : 3017003
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.stgit.jumionative",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.documentsui",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.externalstorage",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.htmlviewer",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.javapapers.android.androidgps",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.hotspotlauncher",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.mms.service",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.providers.downloads",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.wappushsi",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.android.sdm.plugins.connmo",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.example.android.testing.espresso.BasicSample.test",
                "version" : 0
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.android.settings.diag_mdlog",
                "version" : 4
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.vzw.hss.myverizon",
                "version" : 40
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.browser.provider",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.entitlement",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.ccc.checkin",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.programmenu",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.handyapps.currencyexchange",
                "version" : 56
            }, {
                "pkg" : "paxcreation.com.multipleviewinrecycleview",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.ccc.mainplm",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.motgeofencesvc",
                "version" : 10001
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.configupdater",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.groundloopnoisepreventer",
                "version" : 10101
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.orgname.linkedIn",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.ccc.cce",
                "version" : 6
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.ccc.ota",
                "version" : 71000
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.ccc.notification",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.orgname.password",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.defcontainer",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.providers.downloads.ui",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.vending",
                "version" : 80750800
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.pacprocessor",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.pgmsystem2",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.stgit.audio",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.bodyguard",
                "version" : 10257
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.motodisplay.env",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.joeykrim.rootcheck",
                "version" : 136
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.demomode",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.certinstaller",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.mobisystems.fileman",
                "version" : 14500
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.marvin.talkback",
                "version" : 40501000
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.android.sdm.plugins.diagmon",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.InvokingAdapterProcedures",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "android",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.contacts",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.android.provisioning",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.vzw.apnservice",
                "version" : 12
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.vzw.phone.extensions",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.hindi",
                "version" : 457
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.stk",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.AuthenticateFingerPrint",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.orgname.PushNotification",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.backupconfirm",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.migrate",
                "version" : 16044
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.vzw.settings.extensions",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.manoj.dlt",
                "version" : 202
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.launcher",
                "version" : 103001
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.androidmyway.demo.proxymityalert",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.deskclock",
                "version" : 45200512
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.mbfs.mra.android.tablet",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.example.hello",
                "version" : 10000
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.gm",
                "version" : 58315863
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.kony.sample",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.moodles",
                "version" : 301
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.motocit",
                "version" : 117
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.example.googleLogin",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.koushikdutta.vysor",
                "version" : 1477720800
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.zxing.client.android",
                "version" : 105
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.setupwizard",
                "version" : 200
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.qualcomm.qcrilmsgtunnel",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.ford.applinkcatalog",
                "version" : 10001
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.providers.settings",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.sharedstoragebackup",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.email",
                "version" : 7008110
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.kony.KitchenSinkApp",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.music",
                "version" : 3120
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.printspooler",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.sample.httpurl",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.dreams.basic",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "io.selendroid.testapp",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.kony.FunctionPreviewApp",
                "version" : 28
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.MotGallery2",
                "version" : 304138
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.stgit.portfolio.dravya",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.inputdevices",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.android.nativedropboxagent",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.android.jvtcmd",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.lenovo.anyshare.gps",
                "version" : 4030608
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.motosignature.app",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.dropbox.android",
                "version" : 1120200
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.vznavigator.Generic",
                "version" : 907073
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.android.buacontactadapter",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.apps.cloudprint",
                "version" : 113
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.chrysler.tvauth",
                "version" : 9
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.apps.docs",
                "version" : 62113533
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.apps.maps",
                "version" : 932100122
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.apps.plus",
                "version" : 416251307
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.dataoffloading",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.webview",
                "version" : 270408100
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.fmrecording",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.localwipe.policy",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.contacts.preloadcontacts",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.server.telecom",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.android.providers.settings",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.facelock",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.keychain",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.gm.exchange",
                "version" : 508255
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.chrome",
                "version" : 270408101
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.zzgo.main",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.SSOApp",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.dialer",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.sample.handlingcookies",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.street",
                "version" : 18102
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.gms",
                "version" : 9683234
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.gsf",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.tts",
                "version" : 210309111
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.partnersetup",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.genie",
                "version" : 104037
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.nfcui",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.setup",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.CallerApp",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.packageinstaller",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.videos",
                "version" : 36160
            }, {
                "pkg" : "stg.com.shuttleclient",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.proxyhandler",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.lmi.motorola.rescue",
                "version" : 74522
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.apps.hangoutsdialer",
                "version" : 1642
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.ionicframework.ionicgeolocationdemo761609",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.customermobile.preload.vzw",
                "version" : 10
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.feedback",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.calendar",
                "version" : 2014102770
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.onetimeinitializer",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.managedprovisioning",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.launcherconfig",
                "version" : 10000000
            }, {
                "pkg" : "de.j4velin.wifiAutoOff",
                "version" : 173
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.example.yeshwanthkk.ocr",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.dreams.phototable",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.mapmywalk.android2",
                "version" : 16060200
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.moto",
                "version" : 20301
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.slpc",
                "version" : 10112
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.DCMobile",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.orgname.Print",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.example.distancematrix",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.providers.partnerbookmarks",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.gsf.login",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.jms.zoomrotation",
                "version" : 2
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motricity.verizon.ssodownloadable",
                "version" : 229
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.vzw.loader",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.wallpaper.livepicker",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.mmi.explore",
                "version" : 16
            }, {
                "pkg" : "portfolio.stgit.com.portfolio",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.example.helloapp",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.example.webserviceexample",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.motocare.internal",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.example.yeshwanthkk.indoorpositioning",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.chrysler.dailysales",
                "version" : 10000
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.Print",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "org.mozilla.firefox",
                "version" : 2015422361
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.inputmethod.korean",
                "version" : 745
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.karthi.testApp",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.fmplayer",
                "version" : 1100089
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.backuptransport",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.audioeffects",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.fsp.android.friendlocator",
                "version" : 15200
            }, {
                "pkg" : "youten.redo.ble.ibeacondetector",
                "version" : 3
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.linkedin.android",
                "version" : 88700
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.settings",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.inputmethod.pinyin",
                "version" : 421
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.stg.demokpns",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.calculator2",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.apps.books",
                "version" : 30315
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.qualcomm.location",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.hecorat.azplugin",
                "version" : 6
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.lmi.motorola.rescuesecurity",
                "version" : 74522
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.slpc_sys",
                "version" : 10001
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.setupwizard.phoneservice",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.example.linkedinintegration",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.example.yeshwanthkk.beaconpositioning",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.actions",
                "version" : 111005
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.ionicframework.ionicbeacon700665",
                "version" : 18
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.orgname.FirstSPA",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.vpndialogs",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.talk",
                "version" : 23256370
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.bach.modemstats",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.SignInWithGoogle",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.phone",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.shell",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.ibm.appcenter",
                "version" : 80
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.providers.userdictionary",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.orgname.sample",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "jp.co.omronsoft.iwnnime.ml",
                "version" : 32
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.orgname.DirectYourFriend",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.location.fused",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.systemui",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.motodisplay",
                "version" : 21110214
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.fusionone.android.sync.vzbuaclient",
                "version" : 2901144
            }, {
                "pkg" : "edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr",
                "version" : 33
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.setupwizard.devicesetup",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.example.android.screencapture",
                "version" : 0
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.play.games",
                "version" : 22090004
            }, {
                "pkg" : "io.appium.unlock",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.apps.magazines",
                "version" : 2015061020
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.bluetooth",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.qualcomm.timeservice",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.androidforwork",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.qualcomm.atfwd",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.providers.contacts",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.setupwizard.controller",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.android.captiveportallogin",
                "version" : 22
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.so",
                "version" : 2010001
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.verizon.messaging.vzmsgs",
                "version" : 30271
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.verizon.llkagent",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.motorola.android.dm.service",
                "version" : 2
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.gotv.nflgamecenter.us.lite",
                "version" : 1110317
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.verizon.permissions.appdirectedsms",
                "version" : 1
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.hp.android.printservice",
                "version" : 86
            }, {
                "pkg" : "com.google.android.inputmethod.latin",
                "version" : 24512315
            }
        ]
    };
```

How can I send this from my client to adapter using WLResourceRequest?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WLResourceRequest.sendFormParameters(json)` to do this. For more details [refer to this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WLResourceRequest.html#sendFormParameters).

To send json,queryparameters,header etc together in a single WLResourceRequest call, refer to the code snippet and sample [in this link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/resource-request/javascript/).

Comment: I tried this option. But I am able to access this input at adapter implementation. I am passing three values from my client, 

var params = [data,deviceId,token]; // data is an array JSON which you can see above. deviceId and token is a string..   
var newParams = {'params' : JSON.stringify(params)};

resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(newParams)


this is how I send. But I am not able to access that "data" in adapter.js

Please help me out by a sample code

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks. I have already gone through those. they are saying that I need to pass array as a string with "params" as queryParamater. My question is whether I can send an array JSON inside that querParam array

Answer (score 0):

What if you stringify() the data variable before it gets assigned to the params variable?

Something like this:

```
var JSONData  = JSON.stringify( data );
var params    = [JSONdata, deviceid, token];
var newParams = {"params" : JSON.stringify( params )};
resourceRequest.sendFormParameters( newParams )
```

I think you'd have to JSON.parse() the data variable inside the Javascript adapter.  I'm going to try that out when I get a chance...

-Paul Horan-

Comment: I have tried stringifying in client side and parsing that in adapter side. Still I am facing the same issue.